# JQuery -- Uncaught ReferenceError: countChars is not defined

Tags: jquery, function

I get the error in the heading.  Might be missing something simple.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id = "block1"onkeyup="countChars()"></textarea>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js">

  function countChars() {

      block1Chars++;
  }

  var block1Chars = 0;
</script>
```

Comment: Close your first script tag/element, and add a second (w/o `src`) below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need separate `script` tags for jQuery and your custom code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function countChars() {

      block1Chars++;
  }

  var block1Chars = 0;
</script>
```